# how to get the value of the current iteration when using try catch for map

Tags: clojure

The following code failed because "b" is not a valid number. But how to catch it and print the log as "It is b which cause the error, please fix it"? the difficulty is how to get the value of  the current iteration which caused the failure. how to use try/catch to do that?

```
=> (map #(Float/parseFloat %)  ["1" "b"])
NumberFormatException For input string: "b"  sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString (FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(defn parse-incredulously [x]
  (try (Float/parseFloat x)
       (catch Exception e
         (println (format "It is %s which cause the error, please fix it" x)))))

(map parse-incredulously ["1" "b"])
```